# Change the value of input tag based on other input without jQuery

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I have 2 input tags

```
Title:
    <b-input
      style="width: 50%"
      v-model="value.title"
      class="input-element"
      placeholder="Title"
      v-on:click="greet"
    />
Id:
    <b-input
      id="id"
      style="width: 50%"
      class="input-element"
      placeholder="Id"
      v-model="value.id"
    />
```

Whenever I write something in ,I want the value of  input to be updated the same as value of title in lowercase.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your question. What is it you want to do? And what have you already tried so far?

Comment: I want to change the value of one input box based on other input box's value. I want to use something like document.querySelector("id").innerHTML , but innerHTML isn't working on input.

Comment: So if you put `TEST` into the `title` input, it should be reflected in the `id` input, but shown as `test`?

Comment: @Djip yes. Exactly that's what I want

Comment: What should happen then if the user writes anything into the ID input?

Comment: I have to bind both the input tags differently. So if user changes ID input, then it's v-model must change.

Comment: So if a user enter something into `title`, it should be lowercased to `id` automatically, but you should still be able to change `id` even after the title has been "copied" to it?

Comment: So if the user inputs `TEST` into the title input, the id input should be `test`. The user can then change the id input to `TeSt` and that should now be the value of the field. If the user then changes the title input again to `TESTS` the id input should reflect this change and be `tests`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a watcher to watch for any changes made to `title` and set the `id` to the lowercase value.

This allows the user to still manually update the `ID` input. While having it overridden whenever the title changes.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      value: {
        id: "",
        title: ""
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    'value.title'(newVal) {
      this.value.id = newVal.toLowerCase();
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.1.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.1.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<div id="app" class="p-3">
  <b-btn @click="value.title = 'TEST'">Set title to TEST</b-btn><br />
  <label>Title: </label>
  <b-input v-model="value.title"></b-input>
  <label>ID: </label>
  <b-input v-model="value.id"></b-input>

  <div class="mt-2">
  Title: {{ value.title }}<br />
  ID: {{ value.id }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a computed field that changes the title to lowercase and then make the v-model of the id input to use that computed field